# Is it possible to print a greek character (e.g. theta) instead of a number on the x-axis of a pgfplot diagram?

Tags: pgfplots

Hey guys I have the following LaTeX code:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        domain=-50:50,
        xmin=-50, xmax=50,
        ymin=0, ymax=1.3,
        samples=100,
        axis y line=center,
        axis x line=middle,
        xlabel = {net},
        ylabel = {\(f(net)\)},
        xtick = \empty,
        ytick = {0.5, 1}
    ]
        \addplot+[mark=none,red,domain=-50:0] {0};
        \addplot+[mark=none,red,domain=0:50] {1};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

Is it possible to put the greek character theta on the x-axis of a diagram right where 0 would have been?

Thanks for your help

schnickers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear to me where you want it, two methods are shown below. In the first an `extra x tick` is added with a custom label (depending on where you want it, you might want to use `y` instead of `x`). In the second a `\node` is added next to the origin, and that you can of course position anywhere you like.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        domain=-50:50,
        xmin=-50, xmax=50,
        ymin=0, ymax=1.3,
        samples=100,
        axis y line=center,
        axis x line=middle,
        xlabel = {net},
        ylabel = {\(f(\mathrm{net})\)},
        xtick = \empty,
        ytick = {0.5, 1},
        extra x ticks={0},extra x tick labels={$\theta$}
    ]
        \addplot+[mark=none,red,domain=-50:0] {0};
        \addplot+[mark=none,red,domain=0:50] {1};

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        domain=-50:50,
        xmin=-50, xmax=50,
        ymin=0, ymax=1.3,
        samples=100,
        axis y line=center,
        axis x line=middle,
        xlabel = {net},
        ylabel = {\(f(\mathrm{net})\)},
        xtick = \empty,
        ytick = {0.5, 1}
    ]
        \addplot+[mark=none,red,domain=-50:0] {0};
        \addplot+[mark=none,red,domain=0:50] {1};

        \node [above left] at (0,0) {$\theta$};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```